# jQuery ajax cannot call WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, webmethod

My problem seems to have very simple solution and after searching on the SO and googling I couldn't find it.

I've got a client script which is located in UrlUpdatePage.aspx. It's periodically making a call to get json from aspx to get current status of the operation and show message to user. Below is ajax call:

```
  var listenForStatusChanges = function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/UrlUpdatePage.aspx/GetRunningState",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {
          alert(data.IsRunning);
        }
      });
    };
```

In code-behind file UrlUpdatePage.cs I have such a method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetRunningState()
{
    ...
    return jsonObj;
}
```

The problem is when the ajax call is made, the `GetRunningState`method isn't triggered in debug mode and `success` callback isn't as well. Moreover, when I look at the details of the request in Firebug, the request is made but from the response tab I can see the call returns html markup, not the json data.

What should be done to expose `GetRunningState` method to the client and get the json from the server? I use .NET 4

Comment: copy the response u get as html into a notepad, save it as a `html` file, and open it. and voila! there's your error. next post that screenshot here.

Comment: @passionateCoder I cannot upload screenshots but there's no point in it: the response shows just the markup of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why I get html markup instead of json: [due to security reasons](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) `UrlUpdatePage.aspx/GetRunningState` is only callable via HTTP POST request.
So, I need to use POST verb in two places: `type: 'POST'` and `UseHttpGet = false`.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: I admit it works with `GET` in the test project but not in one I referred to :( So the solution may lay in Web.config but I don't know where

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first slash from the URL. Like that:

```
url: "UrlUpdatePage.aspx/GetRunningState",
```

Comment: Try to remove the `scripmethod` annotation. I did it many times and it worked successfully out of the box, just settin the `webmethod` anotation. Don't forget to compile server side code ;)